# EC2 instance has SQL installed

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

How to identify if an EC2 instance has SQL installed. Through the AWS portal ?

[image: Systems Manager alarm]

This image is an example of where I'm looking to identify whether or not the instance has a database installed.

Comment: https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/inventory ?

Comment: @Caldazar, you can put screenshot of the screen, because i dont have acess AWS Account

Comment: You _can't_ identify if SQL is installed on a server because access to the server, and all software on it, is controlled by the Operating System. AWS can't see "inside" the instance. However, as @Caldazar points out, you could use Systems Manager to run a script on the instance that can take an inventory of what it contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that through the AWS portal as the portal has no insight into what applications you are running on your instance.

You must SSH into your instance, perhaps using `Systems Manager` and check is SQL is installed.

`mysql -V` will allow you to check if MySql is installed, other types of databases will have similar commands.

##### Update based on comment:

As you are installing from a preconfigured OS you can see whats included in the `instance details` tab from the EC2 Web Console.

[image]

Or you can run the following command from your CLI:

`aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-id <your instance id> --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].PlatformDetails'`

```
[
    [
        "Windows with SQL Server Standard"
    ]
]
```

Comment: I understand. 
But, when i select the EC2 instance specifications, i need selec the Operating system. Some Operating Systems have database , for example: Windows Server with SQL Server Web, Windows Server with SQL Server Enterprise, Linux with SQL Server Enterprise.
this spec, shouldn't it be on the AWS portal?